# In Spring AOP, what is the difference between joinPoint.proceed and method.invoke?

Tags: java, spring, reflection, aop, spring-aop

I don't know the difference between the two methods, because they all work very well.

The reason I tried to use `method.invoke` is that I want to call other methods instead in the aspect.

```java
@Component
public class DefaultApiInvokeFacadeImpl implement ApiInvokeFacade {
    @Override
    public ResponseDTO request(RequestDTO request,Class bodyClazz) {
        return request(request,bodyClazz,null);
    }
    @Override
    public ResponseDTO request(RequestDTO request,Class bodyClazz,InvokeContext invokeContext) {
        // .... some codes
        return response;
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
@Aspect
public class HttpInvokeAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(" +
            "public io.github.lvyahui.http.api.model.ResponseDTO io.github.lvyahui.http.api.facade.impl.DefaultApiInvokeFacadeImpl" +
            ".request(..)" +
            ")")
    public void httpApi() {
    }

    @Around("httpApi()")
    public Object arroud(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Object [] args = Arrays.copyOf(joinPoint.getArgs(),3);
        Method method = joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringType().getDeclaredMethod("request", RequestDTO.class,
                    Class.class, InvokeContext.class)
        // A
        /// Object ret = joinPoint.proceed(args);
        // B
        Object ret = method.invoke(joinPoint.getTarget(),args);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you need `method.invoke` to call other methods, just call the method. Why even use reflection for that in this way.  Problem of not using `proceed` is that you might bypass other interceptors/aop advices as you are now directly calling the method instead of letting the AOP framework handle it, potentially breaking other things applied through AOP (like transactions, security etc.).

Comment: I agree. Your pointcut is so specific, you only intercept `DefaultApiInvokeFacadeImpl.request(..)`, then you call the same `request(..)` method again via reflection. This is so contrived, I wonder how you even got the idea to do that. Please show an example of what you **really** want to do because this example does not make any sense. You talked about calling another method instead. Which one? One from the same class, from another class?